# Canon t1i DSLR LCD screen discoloration

Tags: canon, dslr, canon-500d, lcd

I have a new Canont T1i DSLR camera that is about 6 months old. I have not use it for 2 months. Today when I take it out. I turned on the camera. The LCD screen is showing a lot of discolorations. With blue and green and red etc.

Is something wrong with my camera? what could I do to fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean individual bright pixels of blue, red, and green, or blotches of color, or something else?

Comment: It look like a blotches of color, like one part of screen is red, and other part is green and blue, it's messed up looking. Usually the LCD shows the settings for camera in preset color (like white, green, one single color).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your LCD needs replacing. Without any pictures of the actual screen it's hard to tell but generally you can only adjust the LCD screen's brightness and not the colour.

Does this happen in the menu as well? If it only happens on live view then it could be the settings. If it's on the menu too then likely the LCD is faulty.

I would suggest a basic camera reset and see if that resolves anything. This will be in the menu of you're unsure.

If not, take it to Canon or a service agent.

Comment: Thanks. Reset the settings doesn't work. The camera still works taking photos. When viewing settings or doing preview of photo on LCD, it shows the weird color. Not sure why it all the sudden just fail like that.

Comment: Yep, sometimes these things fail. I was going to suggest tapping the screen as it can sometimes be a connection issue but it's not a good idea to advise hitting your camera and likely it wouldn't have done anything anyway. LCD replacements are usually the cheapest repair so take a look around if you like the camera.

Comment: I took it to a Canon services (have a Canon factory nearby) and have the LCD screen replaced for almost $300.

Comment: It's been a few years since I replaced the LCD screen on my camera and it works very nicely still. Thinking back, the problem possibly is caused by excess moisture in storage.

Comment: Even with the screen like this will my printed pics look like that also?